# Pass Many Classes To Method

Tags: c#, linq, class, arguments

Good time of the day!
I'm trying to pass few classes, which inherit from one base class.
The structure looks as follows:

- **Permission Class** - Permisions for user

  - **Edit : Permission** - Ability to edit record
  - **Delete : Permission** - Ability to delete record
  - **Create : Permission** - Ability to create record
- **User Class** - User class

  - **private Permission[] permissions** - permissions available for user
  - **public void AddDefaultPermissions(Permission[] permissions)**

What i can't figure out, is how to pass multiple permissions to this function and check if permission has already been added. What i was thinking of is to allow something like the following method call:

```
AddDefaultPermissions(Edit, Delete, Create);
```

**Permission Class:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Permission {

private int permissionID;
private string permissionName;
private string permissionDescription;
private int accessStartTimestamp;
private int accessEndTimestamp;

public int PermissionID {
    get { return permissionID; }
    set { permissionID = value; }
}

public string PermissionName {
    get { return permissionName; }
    set { permissionName = value; }
}

public string PermissionDescription {
    get { return permissionDescription; }
    set { permissionDescription = value; }
}

public int AccessStartTimestamp {
    get { return accessStartTimestamp; }
    set { accessStartTimestamp = value; }
}

public int AccessEndTimestamp {
    get { return accessEndTimestamp; }
    set { accessEndTimestamp = value; }
}
}
```

**Edit Class:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Edit : Permission {

public Edit() {
    PermissionID = 1;
    PermissionName = "Edit";
    PermissionDescription = "Allow user to edit records";
    AccessStartTimestamp = 1488369600;
    AccessEndTimestamp = 1491048000;
}

}
```

For checking if permission is already exists, PermissionID variable can be used. This variable is inherited by all of the permission classes and unique for the permission (Edit = 1, Create = 2, Delete = 3);

I saw some examples with LINQ, but couldn't make it to work, since actually never worked with LINQ.
Is it possible to achieve this functionality + to check if permission has already been added to avoid duplicates?

Comment: Could ypu provide some sample-code of your structure? At least to me it´s hard to understand your structure. In particular: what is `Edit`, `Delete` and `Create`? Are those members of the permission-class? Or classes deriving from it? Or enum-members? Anyway to check for duplicates you can simply make a call to `permissions.Distinct(x => x.TheMemberToBeUnique)`.

Comment: If you use the right sort of enum, you can have edit&delete&create all as one option..as edit would be 1, delete 2, create 4 etc.

Comment: @HimBromBeere sure, i'll update question in 2 minutes with samples

Comment: To allow that method call, use this signature: "public void AddDefaultPermissions(params Permission[] permissions)"

Comment: what is `AddDefaultPermissions` method suppose to do? Should it check if permissions are already there in the `permissions` array or should it just add everything from the `permissions` array (I'm asking this based on your methos signature `public void AddDefaultPermissions(Permission[] permissions)`)?

Comment: It should check if permission already exists, and if not, add it. This is just pseudo coded method (because i dont actually know how it should look like)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily eliminate the duplicaets from your input using [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
AddDefaultPermissions(params Permission[] permissions) 
{
    var actualPermissions = permissions.Distinct();
}
```

This assumes your `Permission`-class implements `Equals` and `GetHashCoe` appropriately by comparing their `PermissionID`-property, e.g:

```
class Permission
{
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var p = obj as Permission;
        if(p == null) return false;
        return this.PermissionID == p.PermissionID;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.PermissionID .GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

If you can´t change the implementation of this class you can also use your own implementation for `IEqualityComparer` within `Distinct`:

```
var actualPermissions = permissions.Distinct(myEqualityComparer);
```

If you just want to check if the item was allready added you can just check for a `Contains` which will rely on `Equals` to be implemented as shown above:

```
AddDefaultPermissions(params Permission[] permissions) 
{
    var actualPermissions = permissions.Distinct();
    foreach(var p in permissions)
        if(!listOfAllreadyAddedPermissions.Contains(p)
            listOfAllreadyAddedPermissions.Add(p);
}
```

Or alternativly again - if you don´t want to change the class - use [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if(!listOfAllreadyAddedPermissions.Any(x => x.PermissionId == p.PermissionId)
    listOfAllreadyAddedPermissions.Add(p);
```

Comment: Thank you. I've added some code related changes tho, but everything works!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an arbitrary number of permissions using `params` syntax:

```
AddDefaultPermissions(params Permission[] permissions) {
}
```

To check which permission is used more than once, group and check counts:

```
foreach (var pg in permissions.GroupBy(p => p).Where(g => g.Count() > 1) {
    Console.WriteLine("Permission {0} is used {1} times.", pg.Key, pg.Count());
}
```

Important: the above will work only if `Permission` class properly implements `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods.